# Is the SO search just looking for titles

Tags: discussion

I don't know if it's worth a question, but I didn't find anything, which confirms why I'm asking this question. Downvote me, if you want.

It is exactly the point I was wondering about.

**Test:**
I did some searching with keywords, that I know being in my answers/questions. But I don't get the corresponding results...

When I really need some help, it's quite difficult to find good & professional answers. It is because of loads of *"syntax-asking-not-reading-docs-questions"*?

So here's my question: **Does the search-feature look inside questions/answers too or does it just look in titles?**

BTW: I remarked that there are less "easy questions", which is **very good** for SO because we want to be a high quality repository for programmers questions! (even if that means, that I'm not getting rep that easy anymore!), because that means, that SO is watching on good quality questions/answers.

Comment: It looks in posts too, yes.

Comment: Example: [user:100297 descriptor object \_\_get\_\_ \_\_set\_\_](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a100297%20descriptor%20object%20__get__%20__set__), ordered by votes. The top hit does not mention any of those keywords.

Comment: And sure, the quality of the titles is always important. So are the question bodies! Quality, quality, quality.

Comment: Sneaking in another completely separate issue in your edit... That deserves a **separate** question / discussion. And yes - titles are important.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is the biggest problem of the site, I think!

Comment: The biggest? I think not. We have bigger problems than bad titles ;)

Comment: Ok one of the problems then....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the search-feature look inside questions/answers too or does it just look in titles?

It looks at titles and post bodies. It also indexes other aspects of posts (number of answers on a question, dates, whether it is a question and answer and more).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - It should be possible - sounds like a good feature request :)

Comment: it has serious problems finding [The NRE answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) even with NRE in the dupe title and typing "What is a nullreference" in the search box.

Comment: @Oded: posted as [Boost duplicate post search results by incoming link count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232131)

Comment: @Plutonix: 982 incoming links should be enough of a boost to beat all other hits on those keywords. :-)